# disable a stylesheet in certain wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress

i have stylesheet that loads on all of my pages in my wordpress theme. i want to disable it in landing.php .
The file is in this address: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/fusion-styles/fusion-22528.css
i had tried these codes so far:

```
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
if (is_page_template( 'landing.php' )) {
wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'http://example.com/wp-
content/uploads/fusion-styles/fusion-22528.css', false );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
```

and this one:

```
function se_remove_styles() {
if ( is_page_template( 'landing.php' ) ) {
wp_dequeue_style( 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/fusion-
styles/fusion-22528.css?timestamp=1510985246&#038;ver=4.9' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'se_remove_styles', 99999 );action( 
'wp_print_styles', 'se_remove_all_styles', 999999 );
```

but didnt worked. i had use this code:

```
function se_remove_all_styles() {
global $wp_styles;
if ( is_page_template( 'landing.php' ) ) {
$wp_styles->queue = array();
}
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'se_remove_all_styles', 99 );
```

but it will remove all of my styles.

any help will appreciated.

Comment: Where is this style enqueud? What is its handle name? Using css URL inside wp_dequeue_style is not correct. You can use just handle name.

Comment: i'm new to wordpress coding @Elvin85 . how can i get the handle name? and how can i know  
Where is this style enqueued?

Comment: okay i am adding the answer now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code snippet removes queued CSS called "animate" from your WP frontend.

```
function se_remove_styles() {
wp_dequeue_style( 'animate' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_remove_styles',99999 );
```

So, how to get handle name of queued CSS? There are some ways to do it, here is one of them:

1. Go to view-source:yourwebsite.com
2. CTRL+F and find your needed CSS file.
3. You will see the line like this:

   < link rel="stylesheet" id="fusionblabla-css"  href="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/fusion-styles/fusion-22528.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

You see id='fusionblabla-css' there. Then "fusionblabla" is the handle name you are looking for. (not 'fusionblabla-css', but "'fusionblabla')

After it is done and you make sure that it is working you can add condition to that function

```
function se_remove_styles() {
if (SOME CONDITION HERE)
wp_dequeue_style( 'animate' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_remove_styles',99999 );
```

Comment: so the code changes to this: `function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
if (is_page_template( 'landing.php' )) {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet-css', 'http://oxinchanel.com/wp-content/uploads/fusion-styles/fusion-22528.css', false );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );`

Comment: The handler was stylesheet-css as i checked.

Comment: so how can i address that file in my function?

Comment: The picture i attached is the stylesheat img toing to remove it :

Comment: Remove your own code, COMPLETELY remove it. Then copy paste my first given code. Then change "animate" to "stylesheet" - if it works, then add if() condition.

Comment: function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
if (is_page_template( 'landing.php' )) {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'http://oxinchanel.com/wp-content/uploads/fusion-styles/fusion-22528.css', false );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' ); . did not worked

Comment: Mohammad, remove your own codes for this, and then copy-paste my code.

Comment: i changed the code the way you mentioned above .@Elvin i think the problem is how i address the file in my function.

Comment: no, you didn't.  because you changed it wrong. you need to remove ALL your functions for this, and then paste my code. Else you will not be able to solve this.

Comment: worked dude! you are my hero! i was searching for this for two days!!

Comment: Thanks in advance Elvin